# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable ... in OOP

Tags: python, class, oop

So Im just learning how to integrate two classes in one call and I keep getting the error on the print statement: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. Do I need to create a **str** contructor? Or do I need to intergrate the two classes into one?

```
class Election:

    def __init__(self, place, ballot):
        self.place=place
        self.ballot=ballot

    def place(self):
        return self.place

    def getBallot(self):
        return self.ballot

    def getContest(self,number):
        if self.ballot[number]:
            return self.ballot[number]
        else:
            return False

    def size(self):
        return len(self.ballot)

    def addContest(self,Contest):
        self.ballot=self.ballot.append(Contest)
        return self.ballot.get(Contest)

class Contest:

    def __init__(self, position, cands):
        self.position = position
        self.cands = {"Jones":0,"Smith":0}

    def getPosition(self):
        return str(self.position)

    def getCandidates(self):
        return str(self.cands)

    def getTally(self,candidate):
        return self.cands[candidate]

    def addTally(self,candidate,n_votes):
        self.cands[candidate]=self.cands[candidate]+n_votes
def main():
    elect = Election('TestTown', [
        Contest('Senator', ['Jones', 'Smith']),
        Contest('Mayor', ['Anderson', 'Green'])])

    print(elect.place())
    elect.getContest(1)# --> <Election object at 0x7f4b359cf5d0>
    elect.getContest(1).getTally('Anderson')# --> 0

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is: `elect.place` is a string, and you're trying to call it by adding `()`. `elect.place` is the string `'TestTown'`. Simply refer to it as normal. Don't call it. It's not a function or other callable.

```
print(elect.place)
```

And you can get rid of the getters, e.g. `def place`, `def getBallot`, `def getPosition`, and so on. The instance variables are already directly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these two lines of code:

```
def place(self):
    return self.place
```

See, now your `Election` object has `self.place` as a string and as a function. In this case, it appears to be the case that the string is shadowing the function. To fix this, follow the same convention as your other class functions and name the function `getPlace`.